# UIButton text not showing up

Tags: swift, text, colors, uibutton

I am trying to create UIButton and display a text in it, as well as designate a font size but it will not show up in my Storyboard, using the setTitleColor and the titleLabel!. It will work if I comment those 2 lines out and uncomment the forgot.setTitle (That is currently commented out) however with that I cannot set the UIButton text fontsize. Any suggestions? I have added the subview to my view in my viewdidload.

```
let forgotPassword: UIButton = {
    let forgot = UIButton()
    forgot.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    //forgot.setTitle("Forgot your password?", for: .normal)

    forgot.titleLabel! .font = UIFont(name:"Forgot your password?", size: 14)
    forgot.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)

    forgot.addTarget(self, action: #selector(forgot(_ :)), for: .touchUpInside)
    forgot.sizeToFit()

    //forgot.backgroundColor = .orange
    return forgot

}()
```

Answer (score 1):

The button is not visible because it has no text.

The problem here is that these two lines do not actually set the text, only the appearance.

```
forgot.titleLabel!.font = UIFont(name: "System", size: 14) // This is the font, not the text itself
forgot.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
```

You have to call this line *as well* to actually set any text to appear.

```
forgot.setTitle("Forgot your password?", for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to uncomment the line that sets the title - without a title it's not surprising that nothing turns up.  You also need to change the font line - the `name` is meant to be the name of the font, not the text string to display.  The below works:

```
let button = UIButton()
button.setTitle("Forgot your password?", for: .normal)
button.sizeToFit()
button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)
button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
```